# SQLAlchemy: relationship between tables using keys of different types?

Tags: mysql, oracle, sqlalchemy, relationship

I need to relate two tables using SQLAlchemy 0.7; one is in a MySQL database, and the other is in an Oracle database.

I've already related tables like this successfully where the keys are the same type:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Survey(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'SURVEY'

    survey_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    term_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    # Because the TERM table is in Oracle, but the SURVEY table is in
    # MySQL, I can't rely on SQLAlchemy's ForeignKey.  Thus,
    # I need to specify the relationship entirely by hand, like so:
    term = relationship("Term",
        primaryjoin="Term.term_id==Survey.term_id",
        foreign_keys=[term_id],
        backref="surveys"
    )

class Term(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TERM'

    term_id   = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    term_name = Column(String(30))
    start_date = Column(Date)
    end_date = Column(Date)

mysql_engine = create_engine(MYSQL)
oracle_engine = create_engine(ORACLE)

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(
    binds={
        Term: oracle_engine,
        Survey: mysql_engine
    }
))
```

However, I've run into a snag where one of the Oracle tables' primary keys (`PERSON.person_id`) is a `VARCHAR2(30)`, and the related key on the MySQL table (`ANSWER.person_id`) is type INT.  I can't alter the Oracle table, and I'd prefer to avoid altering the MySQL table.  When I try to retrieve the `PERSON` object through the relationship on `ANSWER`, Oracle throws:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

which appears to be because it's trying a query similar to:

```
SELECT * from PERSON where person_id = 12345;
```

instead of

```
SELECT * from PERSON where person_id = '12345';
```

So, what I'm looking for is a way to tell SQLAlchemy that `ANSWER.person_id` should be converted to a string before using it in the queries it does against the Oracle table.  I've tried to use SQLAlchemy's `func` construct, but:

```
Answer.person = relationship(Person,
    primaryjoin=Person.person_id == func.TO_CHAR(Answer.person_id),
    foreign_keys=[Answer.person_id]
)
```

causes SQLAlchemy to raise this error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine relationship direction for primaryjoin condition 'PERSON.person_id = TO_CHAR(ANSWER.person_id)', on relationship Answer.person, using manual 'foreign_keys' setting.  Do the columns in 'foreign_keys' represent all, and only, the 'foreign' columns in this join condition?  Does the mapped Table already have adequate ForeignKey and/or ForeignKeyConstraint objects established (in which case 'foreign_keys' is usually unnecessary)?`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this same question over on the sqlalchemy Google Group, and got a response from one of the authors with a working solution.  If you're interested in doing this kind of relationship, check out the new page he added to the sqlachemy wiki:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/RelationshipOnCast